# Set minbarSize in chart.js when there are no data or 0/0.1 data in front of thousands of data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have configure chart.js for display chart now, I am facing issue if there is less data in the chart option data then it's bar is almost disappear. I need to display the minimum bar size. I have tried many options but it's not working.

Below is my chart configuration I just want to display minimum bar size even when there were 0 data or minimum data like linkedin.

Thank you in advance!
[image: This is the chart image which has data][image]

```
new Chart('#getassistedlift_chart', {
type: 'bar',
data: {
  labels: lableList,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: lineData,
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Assisted Lift',
      fill: false,
      tension: 0,
      backgroundColor: '#F3B182',
      borderColor: "#F3B182",
      yAxisID: 'right-axis',
      borderWidth: 0,
      beginAtZero: true,
      minBarLength: 100,
    },
    {
      borderWidth: 0,
      label: ommnichannelType2Selected == "conversion" ? 'Direct Conversions' : 'Direct Revenue',
      data: directData,
      backgroundColor: '#387590',
      yAxisID: 'left-axis',
      beginAtZero: true,
      minBarLength: 100,
    }, {
      borderWidth: 0,
      label: ommnichannelType2Selected == "conversion" ? 'Assisted Conversions' : 'Assisted Revenue',
      data: asosiatedData,
      backgroundColor: '#88CBE5',
      yAxisID: 'left-axis'
    },
  ]
},
options: {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: legendFunction("top"),
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
    titleFontSize: 15,
    titleMarginBottom: 10,
    bodySpacing: 10,
    bodyFontSize: 13,
    xPadding: 10,
    yPadding: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
    callbacks: {
      label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
        if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex == 0) {
          return 'Assisted Lift: ' + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel) + "%"
        } else if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex == 1) {
          var title = ommnichannelType2Selected == "conversion" ? 'Direct Conversions: ' : 'Direct Revenue2: $'
          return title + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel)
        } else {
          var title = ommnichannelType2Selected == "conversion" ? 'Assisted Conversions: ' : 'Assisted Revenue4: $'
          return title + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel)
        }
      },
      title : function(tooltipItems, data) {
        const total_val = tooltipItems.reduce((accumulator=0, object) => {
                        return (object.datasetIndex != 0) ? (parseFloat(accumulator) + parseFloat(object.yLabel)) : void 0;
                    }, 0);
                    var total_str_val = setTooltipTitle(matricsName, total_val);
                    return tooltipItems[0].xLabel + ' Total: '+ total_str_val;
                }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        borderDash: [4, 4], color: "#E5E9EB", zeroLineBorderDash: [4, 4], borderDashOffset: 0, zeroLineColor: "#E5E9EB",
        display: false
      },
      stacked: true, // this should be set to make the bars stacked
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'left-axis',
      display: true,
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        borderDash: [4, 4], color: "#E5E9EB", zeroLineBorderDash: [4, 4], borderDashOffset: 0, zeroLineColor: "#E5E9EB",
        display: true
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: ommnichannelType2Selected == "conversion" ? 'Conversions' : 'Revenue'
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        suggestedMin: 0,
        callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
          return intToString(value);
        }
      },
    },
    {
      gridLines: {
        borderDash: [4, 4], color: "#E5E9EB", zeroLineBorderDash: [4, 4], borderDashOffset: 0, zeroLineColor: "#E5E9EB",
        drawBorder: true,
        display: false
      },
      beginAtZero: true,
      minBarLength: 100,
      id: 'right-axis',
      position: "right",
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
          var res = 0;
          res = parseFloat(value);
          res = Math.round((res + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
          return res + "%";
        }
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Assisted Lift',
        autoSkip: false,
        maxRotation: 0,
        minRotation: 0
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

});